# Best Practice for accessing REST API with plaintext password

Tags: security, rest, restful-authentication, plaintext

An application I am building uses AJAX to connect to a REST web service.  Rather than an API key, this service requires a plain text user name and password to be transmitted as POST data with the request for authentication.  Aside from this being poor design, the user/pass combination are the same credentials used to access the website associated with the service making them particularly sensitive.  The service does employ SSL, but the user/pass still appears in plain text in the JavaScript source.  Since the most obvious answer "don't use a service with such glaring security vulnerabilities" is not an option for me, are there any clever solutions for protecting the username and password?

This application makes frequent requests to the API to work with realtime data so I am trying to avoid using a proxy on my own server which would basically double my overhead.  This leaves me hoping for some kind of client side solution.

I will be deploying minified code which will limit readability, but that is pretty easily reversed and it doesn't obfuscate the plain text values so I'm hoping for something more robust.

I'm making use of jQuery and my request is pretty typical.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://my.insecurewebservice.com/api/",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "username": "me@mymail.com",
        "password": "plaintextpassword"
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response, status, request) {
        // perform the usual work here
    }
});
```

Comment: If possible, contacting your web service provider and discuss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to protect such data in that kind of API model. At some point the JS in the browser will need to make an AJAX call with those credentials, and no matter what you've done up until that point (minification, encryption, etc.) it will have to be undone in order to transmit the password to the server. That's security by obscurity, and it's not security at all.

Your options are:

- Have the provider change their API
- Prompt the user to enter the password during their web session (sounds like it's not an option)
- Proxify those requests through an intermediate web service of your own

The proxification option is your best bet, by the sounds of it. It's not all bad, because you could perhaps do some caching or other optimizations in that layer.